# Google play Integrity best practice

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-integrity-api

We want to implement an integrity checking system in our free app that doesn't support sign ups, to make sure the app isn't modified and isn't installed from outside of the Play Store.

We want to make it so that the server only responds to valid apps. We looked into Play Integrity API, but it has a call allowance limit of 10,000 requests per day, so it must only be called on first install launch. We cant find a way to use this system to solve our problem.

Does anyone know any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

You can just email them to increase it to over 1million calls a day

Comment: Do you know how easy to obtain such increase?